# How to write a nested if with a range that has multiple conditions using Python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I recently received an assignment that requires me to write a program which contains a nested if operation. Attached is a image that shows the range and then a few conditions that must be applied to the range.

So based on what I understand, I should show the interest that one will earn on their deposit if the of days to fix it is entered.

This I understand but I have never wrote a nested if that had multiple results. 
If there is any one that can help me with the format it would be appreciated.

[image: Table showing deposit and interest earned over a specified amount of days]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Why don't you try it first. You will learn many other things along.

Comment: Adding to @idjaw, also add [mcve] to your 'reading list'.

Comment: Hello Guys, I was nervous about the whole thing. I was actually jumping the gun as I then learnt how to do the assignment. It is my first time doing any form of programming so I didn't know what I was supposed to do. Thanks for the responses.